# How can I filter the questions by tags with OR operation

Tags: feature-request, tags, search

How can I filter the questions by tags with **OR** operation, I mean:

How can I browse the questions which are in `C#` **OR** `ASP.Net` **OR** `Winforms` tags?

Answer (score 2):

Use the Tag Set functionality on [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/)

You can

- add a list of tags that you are interested in and you can browse questions relating to those tags.
- filter the questions for by stack exchange site or display questions for all sites.
- create many lots of different tag sets, use other peoples tag sets and even get them emailed to you.

Further information can be found on [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/)